# Iterating through a dataframe and adding a new row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new column to my exisitng dataframe.

I am doing this,

```
def test(self, sess, df):

    for index, frame in df.iterrows():
        medical_plan = sess.query(MedicalPlan.id).filter(MedicalPlan.issuer_id == frame['issuer_id'],
                                  MedicalPlan.hios_plan_identifier == frame['hios_plan_identifier'],
                                  MedicalPlan.plan_year == frame['plan_year'],
                                  MedicalPlan.group_or_individual_plan_type == frame['group_or_individual_plan_type']).first()
        sess.commit()
        frame['medical_plan_id'] = list(medical_plan)[0]
        df = df.append(frame)
    print df
```

The df before the loop is ,

```
  wellthie_issuer_identifier       ...       service_area_id
0                   UHC99806       ...                     1

[1 rows x 106 columns]
```

Normally the column and data should be added to this row. But I am getting 2 rows instead and only the last loop value inserted.
df after the loop, column is getting created but the data is wrong.

```
 wellthie_issuer_identifier       ...       medical_plan_id
0                   UHC99806       ...                   NaN
0                   UHC99806       ...              879519.0

[2 rows x 107 columns]
```

How do I achieve this.
Output I should get as below-

```
 wellthie_issuer_identifier       ...       service_area_id  medical_plan_id
0                   UHC99806       ...                     1    879519.0

[1 rows x 107 columns]
```

try 1:

I called the get_id method like below -

```
 def test(self, sess, df):
        print ("in test", df)
        for index, frame in df.iterrows():
            id = self.get_id(sess, frame)
            df['medical_plan_id'] = df.apply(id, axis=1)
        print df
```

Comment: Can you show the exact output you want for that row?

Comment: updated my question. The value should be added on the same row and so on.

Comment: I'm really confused about what you're trying to represent here

Comment: @roganjosh I am trying to get the values from db based on the few values from index 0 of the dataframe and appending that to a new column to my dataframe on same index 0 .What exactly is confusing, could you let me know so that I can update my question accordingly

Comment: "I want to add a new row to my exisitng dataframe." ::adds new row:: "But I am getting 2 rows" You started with 1 row, you added a row, and you ended up with 2 rows. Do you mean you want to add a *column*?

Comment: I think you want to add a column.

Comment: ahh sorry all ...yes I want to add a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def test(self, sess, df):
     def get_id(frame):
            medical_plan = sess.query(MedicalPlan.id).filter(MedicalPlan.issuer_id == frame['issuer_id'],
                                          MedicalPlan.hios_plan_identifier == frame['hios_plan_identifier'],
                                          MedicalPlan.plan_year == frame['plan_year'],
                                          MedicalPlan.group_or_individual_plan_type == frame['group_or_individual_plan_type']).first()
            sess.commit()
            return list(medical_plan)[0]
      df['medical_plan_id']=df.apply(get_id, axis =1)
      print(df)
```

If you want `medical_plan_id` to be an int, you can change the last line of `get_id` to `return int(list(medical_plan)[0])`. Also, you probably could do

```
    medical_plan = sess.query(MedicalPlan.id).filter(
            all([MedicalPlan.attribute == frame.attribute for attribute in 
                 ['issuer_id','hios_plan_identifier','plan_year','group_or_individual_plan_type']])).first()
```

or

```
        attributes = ['issuer_id','hios_plan_identifier','plan_year','group_or_individual_plan_type']
        medical_plan = sess.query(MedicalPlan.id).filter(all(MedicalPlan[attributes]==frame[attributes])).first())
```

(I can't say for certain whether that will work without knowing what kind of object `MedicalPlan` is.)

Comment: Updated the question with the way I am calling the method. I am getting `TypeError: ("'int' object is not callable", u'occurred at index 0')` error. Is this the way I should call?

Comment: You're calling it in a for-loop? The `apply` keyword loops for you. What I posted was supposed to replace the whole function. I've edited to be more clear.

Comment: In this , sometimes I am getting `SettingWithCopyWarning:` warning. How can I avoid this